# Why use homogeneous coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am having trouble understand the use of homogeneous coordinates for when describing transformations in 3D space. From what I have seen, the only difference between a transformation matrix in standard coordinates, and homogeneous coordinates, is that a fourth row is added, of [0 0 0 1]. Then, when transforming a point, an additional row of [1] is added to the point vector. What is the point of this additional 1? And is it ever a different number? From what I have read, homogeneous coordinates enable perspective transformations to be achieved using matrices and linear algebra, but I don't see the connection....

Comment: You may find this PDF on [Homogeneous Coordinates](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs348a-12-winter/Handouts/handout15.pdf) from Stanford helpful.

Comment: @PM2Ring any chance of an updated link? That looks useful!

Comment: @uhoh I _think_ this article on [Homogeneous Coordinates](https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs348a-08-winter/Handouts/handout15.pdf) from Stanford covers the same material, but in any case, it looks like a good introduction. BTW, the classic text for programmers who want to learn this material is [Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Hughes-Computer-Graphics-Principles-and-Practice-3rd-Edition/PGM29906.html) by Foley, van Dam, et al.

Comment: @PM2Ring thank you for those! A friend has asked for some help with the math behind a self-driving Raspberry Pi car. I came across the term while trying to read about computer vision. I thought it would take a few hours, but when I read several "Homogenous coordinates are for..." it sounds like people are putting their hand in a black box and trying to identify some alien object - each description is totally different. So far I've got that you can do offsets with multiplication (I'm paraphrasing of course). Still looking for my own, personal "Aha!" somewhere; the Stanford handout may be it :-)

Comment: @uhoh Christoph's answer is good. With homogenous coordinates we can represent any affine transformation by a matrix multiplication, and so we can multiply all the transformations that we need into a single matrix that can be applied to every point in the scene. This is both more convenient and much more efficient than having to perform an arbitrary mixed sequence of multiplications and additions on the points' coordinates. Also, because homogenous coordinates handle points at infinity we don't need to do special treatment of the infinities that can arise.

Comment: @PM2Ring yep, mostly what I meant by the ugly paraphrase "you can do offsets with multiplication", but I'll work an example with an infinity in it and see what happens. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The main reason to extend $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb {RP}^3$ by identifying $(x,y,z)$ with $(x:y:z:1)$ is to allow affine transformations be described by matrix multiplication, like you do for linear transformations. An affine transformation $\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ is usually given by $x\mapsto Ax+b$ where $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix and $b\in\mathbb R^3$ a column vector. To be precise,
$$
\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3}
\longmapsto
\pmatrix{
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}}
\pmatrix{x_2\\x_2\\x_3}+
\pmatrix{b_1\\b_2\\b_3}.
$$
Using the extension to $\mathbb{RP}^3$ we may write this as
$$
\left[\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4}\right]
\longmapsto
\left[\pmatrix{
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & b_1\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & b_2\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & b_3\\
0&0&0&1}
\pmatrix{x_2\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4}\right],
$$
where $[\cdot]$ denotes the equivalence class with respect to $x\sim\lambda x$ for any $\lambda\neq 0$. Notice that plugging $(x:y:z:1) = [(x,y,z,1)]$ into this gives you exactly the same result as the original affine transformation.

Now why would we like affine transformations to be expressible this way? Composing linear maps is easy: Multiply the representing matrices. So by going from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb{RP}^3$ we can compose even affine maps by just multiplying the representing matrices.

Another benefit, as mentioned by Gregory Grant, is that we now can do computations with points at infinity. For example putting a light source at $(x:y:z:0)$ for $(x,y,z)\neq 0$, allows us to describe parallel light in the direction $(x,y,z)$ in the same way as we describe radial light from some source located at a point in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Not having to treat points at infinity as special cases is _extremely_ convenient when doing 3D graphics software. And not just for handling infinitely distant light sources: consider what happens if the camera passes through a plane. As the camera approaches the plane, the scale of the plane's projection approaches infinity.

Comment: Sure, there are many situations where this is beneficial!

Answer (score 2):

Homogeneous coordinates allow you to include the so-called points at infinity in the transformation.  So it becomes a transformation of projective 3-space instead of just affine 3-space.
  I think.  I was just going to make a comment but I'm not allowed, something about not having 50 reputation yet.

Comment: Though it seems you've reached 50 points now, I've found this helpful as an answer so please don't convert to a comment :-)